# Django check for any exists for a query

Tags: python, django, django-views

In django how to check whether any entry exists for a query

```
sc=scorm.objects.filter(Header__id=qp.id)
```

This was how it was done in php

```
if(mysql_num_rows($resultn)) {
    // True condition
    }
else {
    // False condition
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the right way to validate if an object exists in a django view without returning 404?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639836/what-is-the-right-way-to-validate-if-an-object-exists-in-a-django-view-without-r)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#exists):

```
if scorm.objects.filter(Header__id=qp.id).exists():
    ....
```

> Returns `True` if the QuerySet contains any results, and `False` if not. This tries to perform the query **in the simplest and fastest way** possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query.

**Older versions:** (<1.2)

Use [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
sc=scorm.objects.filter(Header__id=qp.id)

if sc.count() > 0:
   ...
```

The advantage over e.g. `len()` is, that the QuerySet is not yet evaluated:

> `count()` performs a `SELECT COUNT(*)` behind the scenes, so you should always use `count()`  rather than loading all of the record into Python objects and calling `len()`  on the result.

Having this in mind, [**When QuerySets are evaluated**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#s-when-querysets-are-evaluated) can be worth reading.

---

If you use `get()`, e.g. `scorm.objects.get(pk=someid)`, and the object does not exists, an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception is raised:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    sc = scorm.objects.get(pk=someid)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print ...
```

Comment: `if scorm.objects.filter(Header__id=qp.id).exists()`

Comment: @Alex Lebedev: Yes, this method will be available in Django 1.2. Thank you.

Answer (score 237):

As of Django 1.2, you can use `exists()`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists

```
if some_queryset.filter(pk=entity_id).exists():
    print("Entry contained in queryset")
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. exists() is generally significantly faster than count().

Comment: It also seems to be faster than the `.objects.get(pk=...)` route

Answer (score 1):

Django provides a method called exists() to check if results exists for our query.
exists() method return 'True' or 'False'

```
Class Company(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      year_established = models.DateField()

Class Car(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company,related_name='car_company',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

following are the queries with exists() method

```
1. Car.objects.filter(name='tesla').exists()  
2. Company.objects.filter(year_established='date').exists()
```

using exists in related field - here foreign key

1. `Car.objects.filter(company__name='tesla').exists()`

you can give any filter available and use exists() method

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me!

> if some_queryset.objects.all().exists():
> print("this table is not empty")

Answer (score 0):

`len(queryset)` also works.

```
sc = scorm.objects.filter(Header__id=qp.id)

if len(sc):
    ....
```

Comment: you should not use length on a queryset. `.count()` is better but less performant than `.exists()`. Though `.count()` can be useful if you want to retrieve the number of elements in the query