# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ESC'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
escs = esc.objects.filter(Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('Education_Levels')).order_by(
        'id')
edulevel = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(ESC__in=escs.values_list('id')).order_by(
        'pk').first()
```

When I tried this `print("ESC", edulevel)` I received this message.

```
ESC None
```

how do I get the id of esc?

This is my model:

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    ESC = models.ForeignKey(esc, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: In Python, variable names should be in *snake_case*, in your case, *`student_user`* instead of `Student_Users`

Comment: copy, i will change it now

Comment: @ArakkalAbu it didnt solve my problem sir

Comment: It was a *best practice advice*

Comment: I see, then how to solve my problem sir?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1: you have set `null=True` in foreign key which means that the query set returns object which has null in **ecs** foreign key so you can either remove that null constraint or check if null before any operation of the result of query_set

2nd: It is because your query set is not returning any object (There is no model object in your db which satisfies the filter conditions)

You can confirm this by:

```
try:
 edulevel = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(ESC__in=escs.values_list('id')).order_by(
        'pk').first()
except StudentsEnrollmentRecord.DoesNotExist:
  print("I Did not find anything. Try adding objects first")
```

You can see all objects of ecs model

```
#This is only for debugging process to see what objects do you actually have to opt for suitable filters
query_set = esc.objects.all()
print("ecs")
print(query_set)
query_set = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.all()
print("SER")
print(query_set)
```

UPDATE:

You can also use if condition like this

```
edulevel = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(ESC__in=escs.values_list('id')).order_by(
        'pk').first()

if(edulevel)
  print(edulevel)
```

You can also use count like this

```
edulevel = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(ESC__in=escs.values_list('id')).order_by(
        'pk').first()

if(edulevel.count()>0)
  print(edulevel)
```

Last but not least you can also use exists() as explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089028/11979793

Comment: is there any way to solve that my problem not using try catch?

Comment: What i mean sir is, if that selected data have ID greater than or equal to lets say 5, for example, the ID of the apple is 10, apple >=5

Comment: kindly check the updated answer, i believe you re facing problem#1

Comment: sir kindly check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931877/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-queryset-and-int