# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'QuerySet' and 'int'

Tags: django

I just want that if the escs is greater than or equal to **id(5)** it will go to my **if** , if not it will go to my **else**

```
studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=args)
escs = esc.objects.filter(Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('ESC'))

    if escs >= 5:
        ....
    else:
        ....
```

this is the error i get

[image]

What i tried so far is in my if condition **if escs >= 5:** ive tried this **if escs.id >= 5:**

this is the error

[image]

did i miss something?

Comment: `escs` is a queryset, so it doesn't make sense to compare it to a number. Are you trying to check if there a more than five items in the queryset? In that case you would do `if escs.count() >= 5:`.

Comment: no, i mean, if the id of that data is higher than or equal to 5, not count.

Comment: `filter()` returns a queryset. You can use `escs = esc.objects.get(...)` to return a single item, then check `if escs.pk >= 5`. But that will only work if `get()` returns a single item. If it returns 0 or more than one items, then it will raise an error. I can't tell from your queries whether or not that will happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check any record exist which has is greater than or equals 5, you can use following statement:

```
if esc.objects.filter(id__gte=5,Education_Levels__in=studentenroll.values_list('ESC')).exists():
```

Answer (score 0):

Query set returns a list so you can resolve this error by a for loop

```
for ecs_obj in escs:
  # if - else condition on ecs_obj
```

Or you can use object.get() method to retrieve only one object. If it still shows the same error then please update your question the ecs model code