# Filterset field not working for multiple object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

filterset field not working for multiple leave of a single employee leave details, how may i solve this?

```
class LeaveApplicationGetUpdateView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = LeaveApplicationSerializers
    queryset = LeaveApplication.objects.filter()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsSuperUser)
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['type', 'from_date', 'to_date']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        contact_inf = LeaveApplication.objects.filter(employee__code=self.kwargs.get('code'))  # will be refactor
        if contact_inf:
            return Response({
                'success': True,
                'message': 'Successfully',
                'data': LeaveApplicationSerializers(contact_inf, many=True).data
            }, status=200)
        else:
            return Response({
                'success': False,
                'message': 'Not Found'
            }, status=200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you didn't call `self.get_queryset()` to get `LeaveApplication`s. So it makes filter backend classes not being called.

This might be your solution:

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        contact_inf = self.get_queryset().filter(employee__code=self.kwargs.get('code'))
```

And better change this:

```py
queryset = LeaveApplication.objects.filter()
```

to this:

```py
queryset = LeaveApplication.objects.all()
```

And this:

```py
if contact_inf:
```

to this:

```py
if bool(contact_inf):
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089028/7930117)

> Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists() will do more overall work (one query for the existence check plus an extra one to later retrieve the results) than using bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if any were returned.

Comment: That `if contact_inf.exists()` will unnecessarily result in making 2 queries. `if contact_inf:` would use only one query (the query would be evaluated at this step and same evaluated queryset will be used by the serializer). So that specific line is actually better there then your suggestion.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Oh, you're right! I did more research and found that we should use `bool()` instead. I already updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @PreetiYuankrathok Yes but actually there is no need to call `bool` there as the interpreter will do that automatically since this is an `if` statement. :)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for more clarification!