# How to set the incoming object to true or false in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

What I want to do is write "True" if there is data suitable for the filters made, otherwise "False"

```
if ChartSimilar.objects.get(chart=pk, year=year):
   print('True')
else:
   print('False')
```

`charts.models.DoesNotExist: ChartSimilar matching query does not exist.` I get an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django check for any exists for a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690521/django-check-for-any-exists-for-a-query)

Comment: with *objects.get* you have to use try block https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288605/9632638  to don't get any error like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the got query does not exist because the object is not available with a particular id so it's an exception. You can handle it by using try, except block.

```
try:
    ChartSimilar.objects.get(chart=pk, year=year)
    print('True')
except:
   print('False')
```