# For Django models, is there a shortcut for seeing if a record exists?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a table `People`, is there a way to just quickly check if a `People` object exists with a name of `'Fred'`? I know I can query

```
People.objects.filter(Name='Fred')
```

and then check the length of the returned result, but is there a way to do it in a more elegant way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the right way to validate if an object exists in a django view without returning 404?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639836/what-is-the-right-way-to-validate-if-an-object-exists-in-a-django-view-without-r)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Update**:

As mentioned in more recent answers, since Django 1.2 you can use the `exists()` method instead ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)).

---

**Original Answer:**

Dont' use len() on the result, you should use `People.objects.filter(Name='Fred').count()`. According to the django documentation,

> count() performs a SELECT COUNT(*)
>   behind the scenes, so you should
>   always use count() rather than loading
>   all of the record into Python objects
>   and calling len() on the result
>   (unless you need to load the objects
>   into memory anyway, in which case
>   len() will be faster).

source: [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.count)

Comment: When you have really big tables I wouldn't recommend doing a count() on them, because that can take quite some time to find all the matches (in vain, when you only are interested if knowing if there is at least one). If I had to do this, I'd do a select with a limit 1. It will still take a lot of time if there were no matches (worst case scenario), but it will finish a zillion times quicker if any record is actually found. Note: this comment was meant for the proposed count() alternative. I see a recommendation to use exists() in the update, which I agree would be the actual way to go.

Answer (score 47):

An [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) method in the QuerySet API is available [since Django 1.2](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11402).

Answer (score 11):

You could use `count()` For example:

```
People.objects.filter(Name='Fred').count()
```

If the Name column is unique then you could do:

```
try:
  person = People.objects.get(Name='Fred')
except (People.DoesNotExist):
  # Do something else...
```

You could also use `get_object_or_404()` For example:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
get_object_or_404(People, Name='Fred')
```

Answer (score 8):

As of Django 1.2 you could use `.exists()` on a QuerySet, but in previous versions you may enjoy very *effective* trick described in [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12021).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of explicitness: `.exists()` is called on a QuerySet and not an object.

This works:

```
>>> User.objects.filter(pk=12).exists()
True
```

This does not work:

```
>>> User.objects.get(pk=12).exists()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'exists'
```